# Why function return array instead of string?

Tags: php

I have a two class. Class PhotoRepository is responsible for adding data to the database. klasa Avatar odpowiada z kolei za walidację pola. Unfortunately, there is an error with the getExtension function like

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pathinfo(): Argument #1 ($path) must be of type string, null given

I don't know where is problem.

```
    <?php
    class PhotoRepository
    {
        public function __construct(private $database)
        {
        }

        public function AddPhoto(int $id, string $photo, string $date): void
        {
            $query = $this->database->ConnectDatabase()->prepare("INSERT INTO photo (`user_id`, `photo`, `date_to_add`) VALUES ((SELECT user_id from user where user_id = :id), :photo, :date)");
            $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':photo', $photo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
        }
    }

    class Avatar
    {
        public function __construct(private string $avatar)
        {
        }

        public function getAvatar(): string
        {
            if ($this->avatar === '') {
                throw new ValidationException("Wybierz zdjęcie");
            }
            if (!in_array($this->getExtension(), ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'])) {
                throw new ValidationException("Nieprawidłowe rozszerzenie pliku");
            }
            return $this->avatar;
        }

        private function getExtension(): string
        {
            return pathinfo($this->avatar, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }
    }

    class ValidationException extends Exception {}
```

```
    $avatar = new Avatar($this->data['photo']);
    $repository = new PhotoRepository($database);
    try {
        $repository->AddPhoto($_SESSION['user_id'], $avatar->getAvatar(), date('Y-m-d'));
    }
    catch (ValidationException $exception) {
        $errorMessage = $exception->getMessage();
  
    }
```

Comment: The error message says the value is `null` not an array

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever set `avatar` in your `Avatar` class constructor... its an empty function hence the `null` error.

Comment: @mikerojas , That isn't true in my humble opinion. Please take a look at [PHP 8 union types](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#union-types)

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving the error because you're passing `null` as the first argument of [`pathinfo(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) in your `getExtension(...)` method.

```php
declare(strict_types=1);
var_export(pathinfo(null, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pathinfo(): Argument #1 ($path) must be of type string, null given
```

##### Point of correction:

As for those who believe that the `avatar` property isn't set in the `Avatar` class constructor, it actually is. That is simply a short version [introduced in PHP 8 to define and initialize properties](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#union-types).

##### Conclusion:

I personally believe that your issue isn't reproducible.
This is so because by using the shorthand format of defining properties in your constructor:

```php
// ...
        public function __construct(private string $avatar)
        {
        }
// ...
```

You won't even be able to construct your `Avatar` object when you pass `null` as your `$avatar` argument. The `$avatar` data type will be validated at runtime immediately throwing a `TypeError`.

```php
var_export((new Avatar(null))); // Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Avatar::__construct(): Argument #1 ($avatar) must be of type string, null given...
```